# Custom serializer for serializing a List<User> in List<String>

Tags: java, android, serialization, jackson

I've a Model object Group

```
public class Group {
    String title;
    List<User> members;
    String createdBy;
}
```

I'm using Jackson to serialize this Object. Instead of serializing the whole User object in list "members" I want to serializer just the `user.getTitle()` field.
Basically I want a HashMap to be something like

```
{
  "title" : "sometitle"
  "members" : [user1.getTitle(), user2.getTitle()]
}
```

I've written a custom serializer for this

```
public class GroupSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Circle> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(Group value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

        if(value != null) {
            gen.writeStartObject();
            gen.writeStringField("title", value.getTitle());
            gen.writeStringField("createdBy", value.getCreatedBy());
            gen.writeFieldName("members");
            gen.writeStartArray();
            for(User user : value.getMembers()) {
                gen.writeString(user.getEmail());
            }
            gen.writeEndArray();
            gen.writeEndObject()
        }
   }
}
```

But it's not working. How do I serialize only a field of List instead of whole User Object?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I suggest that you look into Jackson's [`Converter`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/util/Converter.html) interface, which seems more suited to the task than creating a custom serializer.

One approach it to create a `Converter` instance and add it to the `ObjectMapper`, so that it will be used for the serialization of all `User` instances.

```
public class UserConverter extends StdConverter<User, String> {
    @Override
    public String convert(User user) {
        return user.getTitle();
    }
}
```

Register it on your `ObjectMapper` like this:

```
SimpleModule simpleModule = new SimpleModule();
simpleModule.addSerializer(User.class, new StdDelegatingSerializer(new UserConverter()));

ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper().registerModule(simpleModule);
```

Another approach, in case you don't want to convert all `User` instances to `String`, is to annotate selected properties with a converter like this:

```
public class Group {
    String title;
    @JsonSerialize(converter = ListUserConverter.class)
    List<User> members;
    String createdBy;
}
```

And have a corresponding converter that looks something like this:

```
public class ListUserConverter extends StdConverter<List<User>, List<String>> {
    @Override
    public List<String> convert(List<User> users) {
        return users.stream().map(User::getTitle).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what im looking for. Thanks. But what is that stream() function?

Comment: Good to hear it! :) The stream() thing is a Java 8 thing ([Read more](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-stream)), and is not mandatory. Feel free to convert the list the way you usually would.

Comment: It's similar to RxJava Observable. Thanks dude. Your solution worked.

Comment: I used this to filter a list using an element's property (isHidden()) since Jackson 2.8 doesn't have JsonInclude.Include.CUSTOM feature, it's incorporated in 2.9.

Comment: Since Jackson 2.2 you can also use `@JsonSerialize(contentConverter=UserConverter.class)` for a `List<User>` field.  This way, you can use a single converter class for a `User` field or `List<User>` field.

Answer (score 1):

Try like below :

Group:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
public class Group {

    @JsonSerialize(using= TitleSerializer.class)    
    List<User> members;

   //getters and setters 
}
```

User:

```
public class User {

    private String title;

    //getters and setters
}
```

Custom Serializer :

```
public class TitleSerializer extends StdSerializer<List<User>> {


    private static List<User> users=new ArrayList<User>();

    protected TitleSerializer(Class<List<User>> t) {
        super(t);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public TitleSerializer(){
          this((Class<List<User>>) users.getClass());     

    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(List<User> users, JsonGenerator paramJsonGenerator,
            SerializerProvider paramSerializerProvider) throws IOException {

        paramJsonGenerator.writeStartObject();
        List<String> titles=new ArrayList<String>(users.size());
        for(User user: users){
            titles.add(user.getTitle());
        }
        paramJsonGenerator.writeObjectField("members", titles);
        paramJsonGenerator.writeEndObject();
    }

}
```

Test :

```
Group group=new Group(Arrays.asList(new User("a"),new User("b"),new User("c")));
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();       
String serialized = mapper.writeValueAsString(group);
System.out.println("output "+serialized);
```

Output:

```
{"members":["a","b","c"]}
```

Comment: I'm curious why this isn't the Accepted Answer, or at the very least why it was down voted. This appears to be exactly what is needed.

Comment: Because this is not working. Don't waste your time on this answer. The output is:
output {"members":{"members":["a","b","c"]}}